# Make simple calculations

Tags: java, beginner, calculator

The problem is instead of doing what is stated in the if statements, does the else line like the if statement is false. However, when printed the variables i am working with, seems i have managed to get the desired expressions. I can't see a problem with the code either so if you experienced coders can please help me. Btw there is probably better ways to do this but I am new to java so no harsh comments please. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise13 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a mathematical expression in the form '<operand> <operator> <operand>'.");

        String expression = read.nextLine();
        int spacePos1 = expression.indexOf(' ');
        int spacePos2 = expression.lastIndexOf(' ');

        String val1 = expression.substring(0, spacePos1);
        String val2 = expression.substring(spacePos2 + 1);
        String operator = expression.substring(spacePos1 + 1, spacePos2);

        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(val1);
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(val2);

        if (operator == "+") 
            System.out.println("The answer is " + (num1 + num2));
        else if (operator == "-")
            System.out.println("The answer is " + (num1 - num2));
        else if (operator == "*")
            System.out.println("The answer is " + (num1 * num2));
        else if (operator == "/" && num2 !=0)
            System.out.println("The answer is " + (num1 / num2));
        else System.out.println("The answer is " + (num1 % num2));

        System.out.println(num1);
        System.out.println(num2);
        System.out.println(operator);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Re. Problem:**

> The problem is instead of doing what is stated in the if statements,
>   does the else line like the if statement is false.

In Java, Strings are objects, and thus the comparison with the `==` operator checks that they are referring to the very same object, which, in this case, is of course not true.
You should use the `equals` method instead, like this (not tested):

```
    if (operator.equals("+")) 
        System.out.println("The answer is " + (num1 + num2));
    else if (operator.equals("-"))
        System.out.println("The answer is " + (num1 - num2));
    else if (operator.equals("*"))
        System.out.println("The answer is " + (num1 * num2));
    else if (operator.equals("/") && num2 !=0)
        System.out.println("The answer is " + (num1 / num2));
    else System.out.println("The answer is " + (num1 % num2));
```

N.B.: I usually prefer calling the `equals` method on the constant (if there is one), in order to avoid possible `NullPointerException`s, e.g.:

```
    if ("+".equals(operator))
```

**Further remarks:**

*Robustness*

I recommend some extra checks to your program, to make sure that it is robust to potential wrong input:

1. Handle the case for invalid operators (now it defaults to taking modulo)
2. **Explicitly** handle the case of division by zero (now, the modulo will be taken, instead of dividing by zero)
3. Handle invalid numbers:

   ```
   int num1 = 0;
   try {
       num1 = Integer.parseInt(val1)
   }
   catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
       System.out.println("Invalid number: " + val1);
       System.exit(0);
   }
   ```

*Braces around blocks*: I recommend *always* putting braces around each block, even if it is just one line. In your case (also, with the correction above), this would look like this:

```
    if (operator.equals("+")) {
        System.out.println("The answer is " + (num1 + num2));
    } else if (operator.equals("-")) {
        System.out.println("The answer is " + (num1 - num2));
    } else if (operator.equals("*")) {
        System.out.println("The answer is " + (num1 * num2));
    } else if (operator.equals("/") && num2 !=0) {
        System.out.println("The answer is " + (num1 / num2));
    } else { System.out.println("The answer is " + (num1 % num2)); }
```

Reason is to avoid accidentally breaking the if-else construct, by introducing new solutions.Consider this:

```
    if (operator == "+") 
        System.out.println("The answer is " + (num1 + num2));
        System.out.println("num1 = " num1);       // (1)
        System.out.println("num2 = " num2);       // (2)
    else if (operator == "-")
        System.out.println("The answer is " + (num1 - num2));
    else if (operator == "*")
        System.out.println("The answer is " + (num1 * num2));
    else if (operator == "/" && num2 !=0)
        System.out.println("The answer is " + (num1 / num2));
    else System.out.println("The answer is " + (num1 % num2));
```

Although lines (1) and (2) do look right on first sight, due to indentation, they are breaking the if-else statement. This kind of issue can be avoided by always adding braces.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Well written. Took a lot from it.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing actual values use .equals instead of ==

Pay attention to the == java operator, it compares the value of two object references instead of the actual value.

For example your variables are stored in memory like this:

```
0x000 "string1" //stored in String operator
0x001 "string2" 
0x002 "string3"
0x003 "string1" //stored in String temp
0x004 "string2"
0x005 "string3"
```

Performing operator == temp translates to "is 0x000 equal to 0x003?", while performing operator.equals(temp) translates to "is 'string1' equal to 'string1' ?"

In other words, use == only if you want to check if two objects are exactly the same objects in the same location in memory

Comment: Thank you. I learnt the difference between == and .equals but always slips my mind. Now I know I am not going to do the same mistake again for sure.